# Excepción "out of bounds" al trabajar con dos arrays

Tags: android, array, excepciones

He conseguido mostrar dos arrays en un mismo activity pero tengo un error que no se como arreglar:

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1

Es un programa deportivo donde muestro resultados. Lo que ocurre es que si el equipo local tiene más goles que el visitante (o viceversa) me cierra la aplicación con el error arriba mencionado, cosa que cuando es empate que muestra el mismo número de items funciona a la perfeccion.

Éste es mi código:

```
public class Goles_Adapter_J25 extends ArrayAdapter {

// Atributos
private RequestQueue requestQueue;
JsonObjectRequest jsArrayRequest;
private static final String URL_BASE = "http://juveniles.esy.es/2015/jornadas/info_jornadas/info_j_25.php";
private static final String URL_JSON = "";
private static final String TAG = "";
private static final String ESCUDO = "http://ffcv.es/ncompeticiones/";
List<Goles_Local> items_local;
List<Goles_Visi> items_visi;

public Goles_Adapter_J25(Context context) {
    super(context,0);

    // Crear nueva cola de peticiones
    requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

    // Nueva peticion JSONObject
    jsArrayRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            URL_BASE + URL_JSON,
            null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    items_local = parseJson_local(response);
                    items_visi = parseJson_visitante(response);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {

                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error Respuesta en JSON: " + error.getMessage());

                }
            }
    );

    // Anyadir peticion a la cola
    requestQueue.add(jsArrayRequest);
}

public int getCount() {
    return items_local != null ? items_local.size() : 0;
}



public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());

    // Referencia del view procesado
    View listItemView;

    //Comprobando si el View no existe
    listItemView = null == convertView ? layoutInflater.inflate(
            R.layout.goles_dos_listas_row,
            parent,
            false) : convertView;


    // Obtener el item actual
    Goles_Local item = items_local.get(position);

    // Obtener Views
    TextView textoNombre = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_Nombre_Local);
    TextView textoMinuto = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_Minuto_Local);


    // Actualizar los Views
    textoNombre.setText(item.getNombre());
    textoMinuto.setText(item.getMinuto());

    // Obtener el item actual
    Goles_Visi item_visi = items_visi.get(position);

    // Obtener Views
    TextView textoNombre1 = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_Nombre_Visi);
    TextView textoMinuto1 = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_Minuto_Visi);


    // Actualizar los Views
    textoNombre1.setText(item_visi.getNombre_visi());
    textoMinuto1.setText(item_visi.getMinuto_visi());





    // Anyadir peticion a la cola

    return listItemView;
}



public List<Goles_Local> parseJson_local(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    // Variables locales
    List<Goles_Local> goles_Local_local = new ArrayList<>();
    JSONArray jsonArray_Local = null;

    try {
        // Obtener el array del objeto
        jsonArray_Local = jsonObject.getJSONArray("golesLocal");

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray_Local.length(); i++) {

            try {
                JSONObject objeto = jsonArray_Local.getJSONObject(i);

                Goles_Local goles_Local_Local = new Goles_Local(
                        objeto.getString("nombre"),
                        objeto.getString("minuto"));


                goles_Local_local.add(goles_Local_Local);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error de parsing: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return goles_Local_local;
}

public List<Goles_Visi> parseJson_visitante (JSONObject jsonObject){
            // Variables locales
            List<Goles_Visi> goles_Visitante = new ArrayList<>();
            JSONArray jsonArray_visi = null;

            try {
                // Obtener el array del objeto
                jsonArray_visi = jsonObject.getJSONArray("golesVisitante");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray_visi.length(); i++) {

                    try {
                        JSONObject objeto = jsonArray_visi.getJSONObject(i);

                        Goles_Visi goles_visitante = new Goles_Visi(
                                objeto.getString("minuto"),
                                objeto.getString("nombre"));


                        goles_Visitante.add(goles_visitante);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error de parsing: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return goles_Visitante;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es porque estas suponiendo que dentro de getView(), el equipo local y visitante tienen la misma cantidad de goles ya que usas el valor position para extraer los valores del arrayList:

```
 // Obtener el item actual
    Goles_Local item = items_local.get(position);
...
...
 // Obtener el item actual
    Goles_Visi item_visi = items_visi.get(position);
```

como lo indicas, el error ocurre cuando uno de los 2 tiene mas goles que otro.

otro detalle importante es que estas definiendo dentro de getCount() el valor
de items_local para definir cuantos elementos tendras en tu Listado:

```
public int getCount() {
    return items_local != null ? items_local.size() : 0;
}
```

aquí debes usar el valor mayor entre items_local.size() o 
items_visi.size() ya que si siempre defines el valor de items_local.size() cuando un visitante tenga más goles, estos no se mostrarían.

Para evitar tu error, puedes realizar la siguiente validación:

```
               if(items_local.size > position){
                 // Obtener el item actual
                    Goles_Local item = items_local.get(position);
                    // Obtener Views
                    TextView textoNombre = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_Nombre_Local);
                    TextView textoMinuto = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_Minuto_Local);
     // Actualizar los Views
 textoNombre.setText(item.getNombre());
    textoMinuto.setText(item.getMinuto());
     }
```

lo mismo para items_visi :

```
if(items_visi.size > position){
...
...
```

para evitar solo mostrar elementos de local modificamos el método getCount() realizamos:

```
   public int getCount() {

if (items_local == null || items_visi == null){
return 0;
}

    if( items_local.isEmpty() && items_visi.isEmpty()){
    return 0;
    }else{
            return items_local.size() > items_visi.size() ? items_local.size() : items_visi.size() ;
        }
```

Comment: Elenasys. perfecto cuando el resultado de los locales es mayor al de los visitantes, pero, si los visitantes es mayor solo muestra el numero de items de los locales, por ejemplo 1-3 solo muestra un resultado de cada uno.

Comment: precisamente lo que comento en getCount()  debes obtener cual de los 2 es mayor y ese valor retornalo en el método, te agrego un ejemplo en mi respuesta.

Comment: Si y estoy agradecido, ¿pero no hay alguna manera que me lo muestre sean los valores que sean? asi cada semana tendria que actualizar la aplicacion. Los resultados solo se saben despues del partido y no se sabe si gana uno o el otro

Comment: con la modificación de getCount() que agregue al final de mi respuesta.

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                             Process: com.rafelcf, PID: 15817
                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean java.util.List.isEmpty()' on a null object reference

Comment: agregue una modificación, aunque tu diseño es un poquito incorrecto, la descarga de datos ocurre en un proceso asincrono así que regularmente se usa un AsyncTask y cuando se ejecuta el onPostExecute del Asynctask es cuando llenas ti adapter con los datos obtenidos del .json, esto es lo que regularmente se realiza.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39444/discussion-between-rafel-c-f-and-elenasys).